# ionic change side menu icon on hover and activation

Tags: javascript, android, css, html, ionic-framework

In my current project I want to add a side menu with icons.
I have two icons for each element of the ionic list, one for normal view and the other for when element in list of side menu is hovered or clicked.

I've tried multiple options I've found on internet but nothing works.

First of all, is that possible?

The nearest to what I want is this example:

http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/side-menu-on-hover

but only changes the darker of the icon, in my case I have two independent png files.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way I found is with controllers:

In my app controller

```
$scope.homeimg = 'img/menu/iconos/home.png';
$scope.MenuTouch = function(){
    $scope.homeimg = 'img/menu/iconos/home_active.png';
}
```